# Can a line in 3-space have all direction cosines $=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

I immediately found that it is impossible since the squares of the direction cosines have to add to 1 and $3 \times (\frac{1}{2})^2 \neq 1$. However, the textbook asks to "interpret geometrically", saying "Hint: Try holding a pencil so that it forms an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with each of the coordinate axes in space". How can I prove no such line exists without using any analytic geometry?

Comment: Can we use Pythagoras'? What can we use?

Comment: @Nathanson Nothing involving the equation of the line.

Comment: Take a point on the line that is at distance $1$ from the origin. Draw the perpendiculars to the axes. By Pythagoras, applied twice, the sum of the squares of the projections to the axes are equal to its length $(\ =1\ )$.

Comment: @Nathanson the line doesn't exist, though. So I would have to prove no such point exists.

Comment: Exactly. If it did Pythagoras' gives you that $1/2^2+1/2^2+1/2^2=1$.